# API Gateway: Cognito authorizer not triggering when CNAME is used in place of invoke URL directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

in API Gateway I have defined a resource /portal with a method GET. This method has Authorization: Cognito user pool authorizer attached. I am proxying requests to a lambda function which returns protected data. After publishing the API and hitting the invoke URL in a browser directly (therefore no authorization headers supplied):
https://name.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/portal

I get {"message":"Unauthorized"} ( which is expected)

However, if I setup a CNAME in Route53, mapping the domain api.mydomain.com -> Invoke URL, and then I navigate to https://api.mydomain.com/portal the protected response is returned.

What am I missing? How would a CNAME have any effect? I'm still hitting the same endpoint in the end.

Thank you!

Comment: You're not precisely hitting the same endpoint in the end, because custom domains provision a slightly separate pathway into the API.  Is your custom domain correctly pointing to the "prod" stage?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. It is. Even if it wasn't, I'm lead to believe that I've missed something when configuring the authorizer. Everything looks correct after pouring through aws docs. With the current deployment, any user could setup their own CNAME, mapping to the xx.execute-api-region.amazonaws.com/stage/resource without the authorizer firing.

Comment: If an unexpected/random CNAME is mapped to your execute-api endpoint, API Gateway won't recognize it and they'll get a 400 or 403 error, depending on the type of deployment, so that part needn't be a concern.  You can prove that by pointing a new name at the endpoint and not configuring it in API Gateway.

Comment: I'd suggest enabling full Info-level logging and comparing the logged results for the two variations.  Also verify that the Lambda authorizer is indeed not firing.  I can't think of any reason to expect this, but you could have a bug that causes it to succeed incorrectly.